# How to find repeated values in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a Customer Inquiry table. Each time a customer clicks Enter, or clicks back to go back to a page etc... the table tracks that info.

```
applicationID      answer                        createDate

1602712         StatusCheck.SOFTDENIED        2018-05-22 02:14:56.893

1602712         StatusCheck.SOFTDENIED        2018-05-22 02:14:57.040
```

The 1st entry is fine but the second entry is where we need to prove to client that the customer is clicking Enter multiple times. We have thousands of records like this.

How can I write a script to track the customers that are Pressing Enter too many times **within a minute...**

Below script gives me the duplicates but I need to narrow down the ones that kept Pressing Enter over and over...

```
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CS.applicationid ORDER BY CS.createdDate) dp,
   CS.applicationid,
   CS.answer,
   CS.createdDate,
   CS.platform,
   CS.mobiledevicemanufacturer,
   CS.mobiledevicemodel,
   CS.browsertype,
   CS.ip,
   CS.applicationstatusid,
   CS.customerstatusid 
   INTO #dp
   FROM dbo.CustomerStatusInquiryLog AS CS 
   WHERE MONTH(CS.createdDate)= 05 AND 
   DAY(CS.createdDate) BETWEEN 02 AND 24 
   ORDER BY CS.createdDate DESC

  SELECT * FROM #dp WHERE dp > 1 
  ORDER BY answer, applicationid
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using? You could just do a self join on application_id and create date between AND createDate +/- 30 seconds. Then get the counts.

Comment: @Error_2646 Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Comment: Can you get a bit more specific? ex. What is too many times within a minute? If they do it at 1:59:59 and 2:00:00 is that within the same minute?

Comment: @Error_2646 something like 02:14:56.893 and 02:14:57.040.

Comment: @KSingh That didn't really answer his question. What about `02:14:56.893` and `02:15:54.999`? Is that within the same minute?

Comment: @Shawn no 02:14:56.893 and 02:15:54.999 this would not be an issue. The issue would be something like 02:14:56.893 and 02:14:57.890 or 02:14:56.893 and 02:14:58 etc... Basically repeated clicks by the customer

Comment: @KSingh Repeated clicks within one minute of each other or repeated clicks that happened on the same minute number? And what about 3+ clicks in the same minute?

Comment: @Shawn yes repeated clicks in the same minute number. would be a problem if the clicks happened 3+ times in  the same minute.

Comment: @KSingh So two clicks only one second apart wouldn't count as long as they happened in different minute numbers, correct?

Comment: I ask because your comments here don't match the original problem description >> `The 1st entry is fine but the second entry is where we need to prove to client that the customer is clicking Enter multiple times. We have thousands of records like this.

How can I write a script to track the customers that are Pressing Enter too many times within a minute...`

Comment: @Shawn my original states 02:14:56.893 and 02:14:57.040 -- this is the problem. So if they repeatedly keep clicking Enter 5 or 6 times or more, its an issue...

Comment: Right, and that's within the same minute number, but the original issue seems like 2:15:59 and a 2:16:00 clicks should fall within the one minute time limit (since they are 1 second apart), even though they happen in 2 different minute numbers. If it only depends on the same minute number and not one minute apart, can you please update your original question to clarify that requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using 60 seconds.
4:01 to 5:59 is still one minute.
5:59 to 6:01 is zero minute.

```
declare @t table (id int, app varchar(40), dtm datetime);
insert into @t values 
(1602712, 'StatusCheck.SOFTDENIED', '2018-05-22 02:14:56.893'), 
(1602712, 'StatusCheck.SOFTDENIED', '2018-05-22 02:14:57.040'),
(1602712, 'StatusCheck.SOFTDENIED', '2018-05-22 02:15:57.040'),
(1602712, 'StatusCheck.SOFTDENIED', '2018-05-22 02:16:58.040');
select * 
from ( select *
            , DATEdiff(second, lag(dtm) over (partition by id, app order by dtm), dtm) as diffSeconds
         from @t
     ) t
where diffSeconds <= 60
order by id, app, dtm
```

It would be nice if the application just did not honor the multiple clicks.  You can use this to disable a button until results are returned.

```
private async void startButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CancelEnabled = true;
    await start();
}

private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    btnTest.IsEnabled = false;
    await Dowork();
    btnTest.IsEnabled = true;
}
private async Task Dowork()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

Or you can cache prior result and just use them if the clicks are with within x seconds.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use `lead` function to get nextTime on subquery,then use `DATEDIFF` function to get less than one minute.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ApplicationID,
                Answer 
FROM 
    (
      SELECT *,
             LEAD(CreateDate) OVER (PARTITION BY ApplicationID, Answer ORDER BY CreateDate) NextTime
      FROM T
    ) T
WHERE DATEDIFF(MINUTE, T.CreateDate, T.NextTime) = 0;
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f9880a/9*

Comment: This would miss 3:59 to 4:01

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a group by that includes all parts down to the second.

```
group by
applicationID,
answer,
datepart(year, createdate),
datepart(month, createdate),
datepart(day, createdate),
datepart(hour, createdate),
datepart(minute, createdate)
```

It won't account for someone hitting enter across multiple minutes (end of one minute beginning of the next). If you wanted to account for that you could join the table back to itself and use date add with a minute long interval that removes results from the second table that fall within that interval.